# Extract specific characters from the string

Tags: python, string

```
i= "March 31st 2013 ntp[22123] Time server offset -.00354 sec"

i= "March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server offset -.0070 sec"
```

The strings seem the same, but once in while, the character count will be different. It won't work if I try to extract only the last part of the string `"-.0070 sec" with i=i [-11:]`.

I wonder if it's possible for me to search for the word `"offset"`, find its position in the string, and use that to eliminate the rest of string in order to keep `"-.00354 sec" or "-.0070 sec"`.

For example, there are 46 characters in `"March 31st 2013 Time server offset -.00354 sec"` and `offset` is the start of the 28th place of the string. The total 34 characters from beginning of the string will be eliminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[text.rfind](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) returns the index to the last occurrence of `offset`:

```
In [162]: text = "March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server offset -.0070 sec"

In [181]: text.rfind('offset')
Out[181]: 38
```

So you can cut the string after `'offset '` like this:

```
In [183]: text[text.rfind('offset ')+len('offset '):]
Out[183]: '-.0070 sec'
```

Or, you could use [str.rpartition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) to chop `text` into three pieces, and pick off the third (and last) piece:

```
In [179]: text.rpartition('offset ')
Out[179]: ('March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server ', 'offset ', '-.0070 sec')
In [169]: text.rpartition('offset ')[-1]
Out[169]: '-.0070 sec'
```

Or, you could use [str.rsplit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to split the string on the last occurrence of `'offset '`:

```
In [180]: text.rsplit('offset ', 1)
Out[180]: ['March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server ', '-.0070 sec']
In [172]: text.rsplit('offset ', 1)[1]
Out[172]: '-.0070 sec'
```

The `1` in `text.rsplit('offset ', 1)` tells `rsplit` to split `text` in at most 1 location.

---

`rfind`, `rsplit` and `rpartition` each operate on the string from the right. So even if `text` contains the substring `'offset '` twice, they will still find the last occurrence of the substring.

Comment: Thank you for several examples. They are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on the word `offset` then, with the trailing space:

```
line.split('offset ', 1)[-1]
```

This takes everything following that word.

Demo:

```
>>> text = "March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server offset -.0070 sec"
>>> text.split('offset ', 1)[-1]
'-.0070 sec'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

strings=['March 31st 2013 ntp[22123] Time server offset -.00354 sec', 
        'March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server offset -.0070 sec']

for s in strings:
    print re.search(r'offset -(\.\d+) sec$',s).group(1)
```

Prints:

```
.00354
.0070
```

Or move the parenthesis if you want to include the `-`:

```
print re.search(r'offset (-\.\d+) sec$',s).group(1)
```

Or, if it is an optional sign, do something like this:

```
strings=['March 31st 2013 ntp[22123] Time server offset -.00354 sec', 
        'March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server offset -.0070 sec',
        'March 1st 2013 ntp[22485] Time server offset .0070 sec']

for s in strings:
    print re.search(r'offset ((?:-)?\.\d+) sec$',s).group(1)
```

With the `$` anchor, it will only return the last one (if found) in the string.

Comment: It was not clear to me if the `-` was a delimiter or a minus sign. I edited my answer...

Comment: Thank you for this regular expression example, I am trying to learn about this powerful function...

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions like this:

```
>>> i = "March 31st 2013 ntp[22123] Time server offset -.00354 sec"
>>> pattern = re.compile('(offset)(.+)$')
>>> offset  = pattern.findall(s)[0][1]
>>> print offset
 -.00354 sec
```